# Need Help To Connect Magento Rest Api using curl

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, oauth, curl

I would like to use cURL to get all orders using rest API. Can I use cURL instead of Oath.

I tried with cURL but returns 403 Forbidden.

I have tried with below code :

```
$params = array(
    "oauth_callback" => $oauthCallback,
    "oauth_consumer_key" => $oauthConsumerKey,
    "oauth_nonce" => $oauthNonce,
    "oauth_signature_method" => $oauthSignatureMethod,
    "oauth_timestamp" => $oauthTimestamp,
    "oauth_version" => $oauthVersion,
);

$header = "";
foreach ($params as $key=>$value){
    $header .=  $key.'="'.$value."\", ";
}

$header .= "oauth_signature=\"".$oauthSignature.'"';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpointUrl);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: how did you pass the credetials? Paste the code plz

Comment: Hello Detzler, 
I have added below code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't event explain it better than the official magento rest documenation:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-PHPExamples

Comment: You are right, but I need to connect with cURL not using Oauth. With Oauth I can easily use.

Comment: you need to follow the oauth protocol to authentificate. You can not bypass this method. If you can't use the OAuth php extension, use a php implementation like https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code,it is working for me and return particular order detail in json format

```
$url="http://localhost/magento2/index.php/";
$token_url=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
$product_url=$url. "rest/V1/products";
$username="admin";
$password="admin@123";


//Authentication rest API magento2, get access token
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Hope,it will help you.

Comment: hey @akgola i am getting response with 404 error page. Can you help me here

Comment: @JayMomaya hope you have replaced the $url, $username and $password values and tried?

Comment: It's been more than 1 year now. I don't remember anything now. @Thamo